# Вывести максимальное и минимальное значение в строковом массиве

Tags: java, массивы

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String firstArray[] = new String[3];
System.out.println("Введите первый массив :");
firstArray[0]= (String) input.nextLine();
firstArray[1]= (String) input.nextLine();
firstArray[2]= (String) input.nextLine();
String secondArray[] = new String[3];
System.out.println("Введите второй массив :");
secondArray[0]= (String) input.nextLine();
secondArray[1]= (String) input.nextLine();
secondArray[2]= (String) input.nextLine();
String content = java.util.Arrays.toString(firstArray);
System.out.println("Первый массив: "+content);
String content1 = java.util.Arrays.toString(secondArray);
System.out.println("Второй массив : "+content1);
String[] thirdArray = new String[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
int coun = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    thirdArray[i] = firstArray[i];
    coun++;
}
for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
    thirdArray[coun++] = secondArray[j];
}
System.out.print("Третий массив: [");
for (int i = 0; i < thirdArray.length; i++){
    System.out.print(thirdArray[i] + ", ");
}
System.out.println("]");
System.out.println("Максимальное значение в третьем массиве ");
System.out.println("Минимальное значение из четырех последних элементов третьего массива");
```

Заранее спасибо:)

Answer (score 1):

Самый компактный алгоритм:
пусть массив называется array

1. сделать копию массива (чтоб основной не менять)

   arrayNew = array.clone();
2. отсортировать

   Arrays.sort(arrayNew);
3. теперь первый элемент arrayNew это минимальный элемент, а последний - максимальный

   ```
        arrayNew[0]  //это минимальный
        arrayNew[array.length - 1]   // а это максимальный
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Можно найти максимальное и минимальное число в массиве таким способом:
Создать методы, получающие на вход этот самый массив, и возвращающий соответственное ему число.

```
public static int getMin(String[] strings) {
    int min = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);

    for (String s : strings) {
        int temp;
        if ((temp = Integer.parseInt(s)) < min) {
            min = temp;
        }
    }
    return min;
}

public static int getMax(String[] strings) {
    int max = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);

    for (String s : strings) {
        int temp;
        if ((temp = Integer.parseInt(s)) > max) {
            max = temp;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

В выводе в строку вы можете использовать:

```
System.out.println("Максимальное значение в третьем массиве " + getMax(thirdArray));
System.out.println("Минимальное значение из четырех последних элементов третьего массива " + getMin(thirdArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

public class MinMaxValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] a = {'3', '5', '1', '4', '2'};

        List b = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(a));

        System.out.println(Collections.min(b));
        System.out.println(Collections.max(b));
   }
}
```